# Guaranteed storage locations

Tags: storage

I'm writing a debugging tool that needs to create a temporary file somewhere.  Normally, I would use `/tmp` but there's no such directory on the phone I'm using.  `mount | grep tmpfs` shows several locations.  Are any of them (e.g., `/storage`) guaranteed to be on every Android phone?

To be clear, I don't specifically need to use `tmpfs`.

Comment: Have root? Mount your own `tmpfs`. Or use `/dev`. If you have only ADB, `/data/local/tmp` is an option. But it's persistent storage, not RAM.

Comment: For my use case, I don't care about persistence either way.  Are `/dev` and `/data/local/tmp` guaranteed to be there?

Comment: Persistence matters because excessive I/O kills flash storage. It's one of the main reasons to use in-RAM filesystems. // I can't say it's guaranteed. But both locations are there in AOSP since years. Anything can change in the next release. OEMs can also modify their version of AOSP.

Comment: @IrfanLatif, I'll accept that as the answer.